# ElasticSearch Frequent Full Index Updating affect on search response

Tags: performance, search, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I have to built an index in Elastic Search which will have more than **500,000** unique documents. The documents have nested fields as well.

All the documents in the index are updated every 10 mins (using PUT).
I read that updating an document includes reindexing the document and it can affect the search performance.

Did anyone faced similar scenario in using EL and if someone can share their experience on the search/query response time across such an index if the expected response for query is under 2 seconds?

Update:

Now, I Indexed **document with id as 1** using update request. Then, I updated **document (id=1)** using **PUT to /_update with 
"doc_as_upsert" : true and doc field**, I see the response contains the *same version as before update for the document* and has attribute *result ="noop"* in the output.

I assume that indexing didn't happened as version of the document is not updated.
Does this reduce impact on search response(assuming there are 100 requests/second happening) and indexing response for my use case if do the same but for 500,000 documents every 10 mins compared to using **PUT (INDEX API)**?

Comment: Updating every document is always going to give you performance problems. Can you be any more selective about what needs to be updated vs. what might have stayed the same?

Comment: Thank You Christofr for the reply. I am going to insert the same documents again every 10 mins and some of the inserts might include updates in fields for few of the documents.

Comment: Hi all, I have updated my post with new information